# POSIX signal handler in Emacs Lisp

Tags: desktop

Does Emacs allow it to implement POSIX signal handling in Lisp?

Specifically, I would like to handle SIGTERM to finish desktop-mode related things.

Comment: As far as I know the answer is "no", but you could try DBus signals: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dbus/Signals.html if that's a feasible option.

Comment: It indeed looks like a feasible option. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `special-event-map` which can be used to handle signals among other things, you can bind a key like `[sigusr2]` there to a function you'd like to be executed on the respective signal.  I'm not so sure whether it works on anything else than `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` though.

edit: Here's an useful example of how one could use it:

```
(defun my-quit-emacs-unconditionally ()
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers t t)
  (kill-emacs))

(define-key special-event-map (kbd "<sigusr1>") 'my-quit-emacs-unconditionally)
```